# javascript calling class methods

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a method in my `Default.aspx` page and I would like to know how can I call this method every 5 seconds through JavaScript ?

```
protected void GetSlideNumber()
{
    var repos = new PresentationService();
    int slide = repos.GetSlideNumber();

    ceckSlide.Text = slide.ToString();

}
```

Comment: what do u actually mean

Answer (score 0):

Use AJAX it can help you. More information can be found at [this link](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

```
$.ajax({ type: "POST", 
        url: pageMethod,
        data: "",
        success: function (result, status) {
        alert("success");
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        alert("ERROR");
    }

    });
```

Comment: He wants to invoke aspx method from JS and not vice-versa

Comment: @asifsid88 Fixed my answer, any chance of getting downvote removed?

Answer (score 0):

like below..

```
<script>
   window.setInterval(function(){
       GetSlideNumber()
   }, 1000);
</script>
```

Comment: how would i call the method above

Comment: I have edited above code..

Comment: this brakes and does not run

Comment: it says undefined method

Answer (score 0):

Make this method as `[WebMethod]` and use `AJAX` to all this method

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "PageName.aspx/MethodName",
  data: "{}",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(msg) {
    // Do something interesting here.
  }
});
```

Refer [Web Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/byxd99hx%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)
More information [here](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
<script>
function sample()
{
alert("<%=GetSlideNumber()%>");
} 
</script>
```